# How to get rid of `UIStackView` magnificationFilter iPad warning?

Tags: ios, uikit, uistackview

I have very simple `UIStackView` with several buttons. Every time I run the app on an iPad I get this warning:

```
<CATransformLayer: 0x147563bc0> - changing property magnificationFilter in transform-only layer, will have no effect
```

The `CATransformLayer` in question

```
(lldb) po 0x147563bc0
<CATransformLayer:0x147563bc0; position = CGPoint (358 160); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 100 316); delegate = <eyeq.RightOverlayButtonStack: 0x147528390; baseClass = UIStackView; frame = (308 2; 100 316); layer = <CATransformLayer: 0x147563bc0>>; sublayers = (<CALayer: 0x147527de0>, <CALayer: 0x14753cbc0>, <CALayer: 0x147544500>, <CALayer: 0x147546870>, <CALayer: 0x147548a70>); allowsGroupOpacity = YES; opacity = 1; magnificationFilter = nearest>
```

belongs to the `UIStackView`

```
(lldb) po 0x147528390
<xxx.RightOverlayButtonStack: 0x147528390; baseClass = UIStackView; frame = (308 2; 100 316); layer = <CATransformLayer: 0x147563bc0>>
```

How to get rid of this warning? BTW, I use Xcode 8 and Swift 3.